# Can not login using az

Tags: azure, ubuntu, az

When I try to login using az (az login), it's giving beloe error in ubuntu..
What is the possible solution for it??

Error:

```
Port '8400' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one  
Port '8401' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one
Port '8402' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one
Port '8403' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one
.
.
Port '8998' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one
Port '8999' is taken with error '[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address'. Trying with the next one
Error: can't reserve a port for authentication reply url
Login failed
```

Comment: well, clearly a network or permissions issue?

Comment: Is there any virus program running? You can check it via the task manager on the machine.

Comment: @Nancy Xiong No, it was working perfectly but after i logged out when I tried to log in again it started giving error... Can it be corporate proxy related issue????

Comment: Try this solution [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7227#issuecomment-589642406), Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Check you /etc/hosts file if you are on linux.
Add entry as ,
127.0.0.1 localhost

and retry. It should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is still relevant after two years, but since I encountered a similar issue and ran into this post, I think it's worth noting the solution I found.

What worked for me was using:

`az login --use-device-code`

As Microsoft recommends here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-interactively

It doesn't use localhost / ports at all, and you can complete the process from whatever computer you want, or if login fails... So it may be relevant for you.

@Nancy Xiong referred you to a solution relying on this extra parameter in the comments, so credits to @nancy-xiong as well